# Auto split comp into separate render items?

Tags: after-effects

Is there a script/plugin that will either (a) take layers from a comp and create separate render queue items for each layer; or (b) use markers in a comp to generate separate renders?

I thought there used to be one ... "RenderLayers" or something ...

Essentially I need to split up a long comp into separate output files.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a script called "rd_RenderLayers" from redefinery, maybe thats what you mean. It does exactly that, adding every layer to your render queue.

Unfortunately his website is on hiatus but the downloads still work, you can download the latest version [here](http://www.redefinery.com/xae/scripts/rd_RenderLayers_v3.1.zip).

Comment: It took me a long time to find that, luckily he gives out the direct links to his scripts if you ask him on Twitter.

Comment: Ha, i tried on twitter .. but no response

Answer (score 0):

The general way to do this now is to use nested compositions and export each composition separately.